# Accessing authentication ticket information when using openiddict

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

Is there any way I can access the auth ticket info set on the auth server when it is separate from the resource server?

On the auth server I can access all the ticket properties I set using

```
var authInfo = await Request.HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var myProperty= authInfo.Properties.Items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.Equals("property_name"));
```

However, when I try this while on the resource server, I am unable to see the same properties.

Comment: Interesting, this should work. Are you sure you're using the validation middleware (and the default token format)?

Comment: I am using the introspection middleware.

I don't suppose I can use the validation middleware if the auth server is separate from the resource server?

Comment: You can use the validation middleware for your resource server if it's configured to use the same ASP.NET Core Data Protection key ring and has the same application name configured in the DP options. You can read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview for more information.

Comment: This is already the case so this will work. I'll give it a go tomorrow.

I feel the correct solution is in your answer below though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access the authentication properties stored in an access token, you must use the default access token **AND** the validation middleware.

When using the introspection middleware, you can't flow these properties. Instead, store them as claims to be able to expose them to your resource servers.